# method fires when change in ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I made a JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/LeoAref/79hqzggg/), and I want to know why with changing the **Done** checkbox for any **item** the `getDoneNum` function fires?

HTML:

```
<h3>Done items number: {{getDoneNum()}}</h3>
..
..
<tr ng-repeat="item in items">
    <td>{{item.name}}</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.done"></td>
</tr>
```

JavaScript:

```
$scope.getDoneNum = function () {
    return $scope.items.filter(function(item){
          return item.done;
    }).length;
};

$scope.items = [
    {
        name: 'Tony',
        done: false
    },
    {
        name: 'Emo',
        done: true
    }
];
```

I didn't use `ng-change="getDoneNum()"` so why is it firing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You use this function in an [**Angular expression**](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression) - `{{getDoneNum()}}` - in a template, over here:

```
<h3>Done item number: {{getDoneNum()}}</h3>
```

This function is called whenever a digest loop is fired. It's easy to check: just debug it (place a breakpoint, etc.) and inspect the calling stack. You'll see the following picture:

```
- $scope.getDoneNum
- Parser.functionCall
- $get.fn
- $get.Scope.$digest
- $get.Scope.$apply
...
```

Comment: but I don't know why this function is fired with every digest loop?

Comment: In short, that's how data-binding implemented in Angular. Check the [Scope Life Cycle](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope#scope-life-cycle) docs for details, it's difficult to give an explanation in SO answer.